# Comparing one array to another

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've got two arrays called Array1 & Array2. Array1 is an array filled with custom objects with multiple properties. Array 2 is an array filled with integers.

I'm trying to compare Array1 to Array2, to see if a int property of an object in Array1 matches an int in Array2.

Currently the code I've got is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.count; i++) {
    Acorn *acorn = [Array1 objectAtIndex:x];

}
```

Any advice?

Comment: `containsObject` won't help you if you're comparing hetrogeneous objects.  You are looking at comparing all of array2 for every element of array1.  That will be slow, but there is probably no other choice (or it might not matter).

Comment: Is order important? i.e. [a.1, a.2] == [1,2] and [a.2, a.1] != [1,2]?

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii No, it shouldn't be. Just as long as Array1 contains all of the ints in Array2...

Comment: Then @jaym's answer is fine, if intProp is an NSNumber (otherwise it lacks @(acorn.intProp)). But note, that while it will work, it will be slow (if you have only 10-20 items, you may skip this note and use the answer), especially if you have a lot of objects in the arrays, it will be somewhere around O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would help, may be!

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.count; i++) {
    Acorn *acorn = [Array1 objectAtIndex:i];
    if([Array2 containsObject:acorn.intProp]){
         // Take this elements in Array 3 and this will be your filtered array.
    }
}
```